# Java finding a WINDOW

Tags: java, netbeans, accessibility, bots

My desire is to create a bot for a game, inside the constrains of the game rules, that would send information to a web-server. 
My first problem is to find the game window, and then find its name.  I been trying to use Assistive Technologies, but not totally comfortable with them. To my limited understanding I need to add a classpath, or something that would set both projects in the same virtual machine.

I am using netbeans right now, and I when I use: (which I blame)

```
public void topLevelWindowCreated(Window w) {
    String name = w.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleName();
    System.out.println("Names of toplevel windows "+name);
    if (!name.equals("Puzzle Pirates"))
        // Only if we're running alongside a Window named "Puzzle Pirates"
        return;
    window = w;
    createGUI();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I will get the name of the window I create, but not of the game.

Resources:
Game - Puzzle Pirates www.puzzlepirates.com (the download version)
Code Examples:
http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/accessibility/docs/jaccess-1.1/examples/Explorer/Explorer.java

Hope you can guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Netbeans isn't to blame.

The classpath bit means that you need to make Puzzle Pirates launch with your bot library available. That means you can't launch PP and the bot in separate Java processes, which is what likely happens if you run the bot from inside Netbeans.

If I understand the sample code comment right, when you put your bot's class name into awt.properties as the example code says, it should get loaded automatically as Puzzle Pirates (or any other Java application) starts. To develop the bot, what you'd have to do is include Puzzle Pirates in your Netbeans project somehow, and start the game, not some test window.

Comment: I been looking for the awt.properties file, and its not on the location. Not sure if the example code is so all that it change, maybe to use accessibility properties, or just that I cant find it. Most probably I need to run my bot outside netbeans, or run the game inside netbeans. I will let you know if it works.

Comment: My guess would be that if the awt.properties file is empty, it's allowed to just not be there and isn't by default – it's the same for swing.properties. If you run the game in one process (the netbeans debugger), and the bot in another (on the commandline), I am almost certain it will not work.

Answer (score -1):

You could always instance puzzle pirates using reflection to load puzzle pirates from your program and thus in the same java process allowing you to hook onto puzzle pirates and grab any necessary information.

Comment: No sample program to validate your claim.